# Vue js and axios not returning any response

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to access OMDB api using Vue.JS and axios.
However when I pass the query from the input field to axios in the `findId` method I dont get anything console logged, no error nor response.data. Why is it behaving like that?

```
<template>
    <div id="search" class="jumbotron">


    <div class='page-header'>
      <div class='btn-toolbar pull-right'>
        <div class='btn-group'>
          <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>FAQ</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p class="text-center justify-content-center">Search for TV Show
    </p>


    <form class="form-inline justify-content-center">


                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Tv shows..." name="search" @keyup.enter="findId(query)" v-model="query" required>


        <button class="btn btn-outline-success  my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>


    <br>

    <p class="text-center"><a id="show-data" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> See the table </a></p>

</div>

</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        name: "Search.vue",
        data() {
            return {
              query: '',
            };
          },
        methods: {
            findId: function(query) {
                axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s='+ query + "&type=series&apikey=XXXX").then((response) => {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                console.log(response.data);
              }).catch((err) => {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                console.log(err);
              });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you check the network tab in your dev tools to see if the request is being sent and what is being returned?

Comment: Somehow the page is refreshed after pressing enter and the response does not have time to load

Comment: Oh, I think I see the issue, lemme drop an answer in.

Comment: you need to prevent the default submit action using `@keyup.prevent.enter="findId(query)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has a submit button on it and you're listening for the user to press the enter key. When an you press enter in the last field of an html form, it submits the form. So change your input field to the following.

```
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Tv shows..." name="search" @keyup.enter.prevent="findId(query)" v-model="query" required>
```

Adding the .prevent on the end of your event listener will prevent the default behavior, which is to submit the form.